# Сделать регулярное выражени

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не могу понять как правильно сделать регулярное выражение для следующего текста:

```
{пример1|пример2|пример3}  какой то текст {пример4|пример5}
```

Нужно то что в скобках разделить на отдельные значения?

Вообще возможно это сделать с помощью регулярных выражений

```
(\{[^}]*\})
```

Так выбирает только то что в скобках, как дальше передать  на обработку то что выбрали в скобках?

Comment: Кол-во групп с фигурными скобками и кол-во значений в них - произвольное?

Comment: Да произвольное значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
<?php
$input = "{пример1|пример2|пример3}  какой то текст {пример4|пример5}";
preg_match_all('/[\{\|]([^\|\}]*)/', $input, $m);
var_dump($m[1]);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a61b1a212825a5d4a14cd6eb2957b9960bfd3504)